# How to change my targets in the dataset after random_split?

Tags: pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I have a dataset for train and test as follows,

```
dataset['train'], dataset['test'] = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset_all, [num_train,num_test],
                                                             generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(random_seed))
```

Is there any good way to change targets and retrieve certain dataset by providing index?
Right now, I am using list this way only to get dataset for labels==0

```
dataloader['train'] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset['train'], batch_size=len(dataset['train']), num_workers=4)
inputs, labels = next(iter(dataloader['train']))
x_train = inputs[np.where(labels==0)]
y_train = labels[np.where(labels==0)]
data_train = My_Dataset(x_train, y_train, transform=None)
```

This way takes lots of time and memory when the size of dataset is too large.

Comment: What do you mean by "change targets", and why are you doing this?

You might want to look into dataset samplers https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-basics-sampling-samplers-2a0f29f0bf2a

Making a custom sampler might be able to do what you want in a more PyTorchic way.

Comment: @Zoom Thank you for the comment. The reason why I want to change the target is that I want to train two different models with different train dataset. It means, for example, if I have 90 train dataset with 3 classes(assumed that each class have 30 data). I want it make it this two different dataset, 1) 90 train dataset with 2 classes (by chaging label 2 to 1),    2) 60 train dataset with 2 classes (by selecting only label 1 and 2)